# nginx serving Django | 502 Bad Gateway

Tags: python, django, nginx

I'm trying to make a big request, how to generate a pdf using Django nginx, Here is my nginx.conf:

I think this request is not high.

What can I do to increase this request from the server?

```
server {
    server_name .urbanarts.com.br;
    client_max_body_size 10M;
    client_body_timeout   10;
    client_header_timeout 10;
    keepalive_timeout     15;
    send_timeout          10;
    rewrite ^ https://urbanarts.com.br$request_uri? permanent;

    location /static {
        autoindex on;
        alias /srv/www/urbanarts/project/urbanarts_cloud/app/static;
        log_not_found   on;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_redirect      off;
        proxy_set_header    Host                    $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Protocol    $scheme;
        proxy_pass          http://127.0.0.1:8007/;
    }

    location /robots.txt {
        root            /srv/www/urbanarts/project/urbanarts_cloud/app/static;
        access_log      off;
        log_not_found   off;
    }

    location /favicon.ico {
        root             /srv/www/urbanarts/project/teste/urbanarts_cloud/static/images;
        access_log      off;
        log_not_found   off;
    }

}
```

Thanks..

Comment: You could use celery to have the request kick off a background process and return the user a URL when it completes.

Comment: I think you may be confusing the `502` error code with `413`. This is most likely nothing to do with the size of the PDF file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not keep increasing the time out, this is not going to help you in the long run.

Instead, use [celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) or [python-rq](http://python-rq.org/) to send your long running task to the background and return a response immediately.